# Convert a string to an array in Go

Tags: arrays, string, go, type-conversion

So in Go I have the following string

```html
["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

I want to turn this string into a list containing each items. What is the best way to go about this? Sorry I am still learning Go but couldn't find similar info on this

Comment: The string is Json, the string is an array of json items, and I want to turn it into a go mapping of strings to interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is JSON (as comments suggest) that has top-level list of objects of same type; you can use `encoding/json` from standard library to parse and simply unmarshal it into a slice of your Go struct type like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Data struct {
    Name string
    Foo []string `json:"foo"`
}

func main() {
    // Unmarshall to slice
    var data []Data

    // Your string with list of objects
    input := `[{"name": "first", "foo":["item1", "item2", "item3"]}, {"name": "second", "foo":["item5", "item6"]}]`
    
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

I recommend reading [JSON and Go](https://blog.golang.org/json) which pretty much explains how to read JSON and in Go.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain enough, its a string that is a json array. So an example would be 
"[{"object1" : data}, {"object2" : data} ]"

Comment: I see, I updated my answer. You should really reword the question so it reflects that.